# Find out if folder on my list really exists in my folder

Tags: bash

I'm trying to find out if folder on my list.txt really exists on my disk in myFiles. But the only output I get is "*No match found*" which is bs because I know some of those folders are real. 
I believe there is something wrong with **If** condition but I don't know what.

BTW the fileFolder variable must be inside quotation marks otherwise I'm getting "*unary operation expected*".

This command  `find myFiles/ -name $fileList -printf '%f\n'` cuts off the path to the folder so instead /home/michael/myFiles/folder_1, I only get folder_1.

Contents of list.txt:

folder_1 folder_2 folder_3 folder_4

Contents of myFiles folder:

folder_1 folder_3 folder_5 folder_6

Anyway thank you for your answers and time.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(cat list.txt);do
    fileList=`echo $i`
    fileFolder=`find myFiles/ -name $fileList -printf '%f\n'`
    if [ $fileList == "$fileFolder" ]; then
        echo "Found match $fileFolder"
    else
        echo "No match found"
    fi
done
```

UPDATE: I forgot to mention that I'm running  this script on Ubuntu under Win10. So I tested my script on virtual machine and it works just fine :) But I need it to make it work on Ubuntu running under Win10 :/

UPDATE 2: I run my scrip with bash -x and this is sample of what I'm getting

```
++ cat list.txt
+ for i in $(cat list.txt)
++ echo $'Folder_1\r'
+ fileList=$'Folder_1\r' 
+ echo $'Folder_1\r'
Folder_1
++ find myFiles/ -name $'Folder_1\r' -printf '%f\n'
+ fileFolder=
+ '[' $'Folder_1\r' == '' ']'
+ echo 'No match found'
No match found
```

I think this is the problem: fileList=$'Folder_1\r'. There should not be this part -> \r

SOLVED: I downloaded dos2unix a ran  dos2unix list.txt in command line. The script finally works. Thank you!

Comment: Don't read lines with for. use a while read loop for both or use an array

Comment: Ouch! You mean `while read -r fileList; do if [ -d "$fileList" ]; then echo "$fileList exists"; else echo "$fileList does not exist"; fi; done < list.txt`?

Comment: Yes, but I think the OP wants to match the content of a file with the output of find.

Comment: Yes, I was unclear on that. Hopefully the OP can clarify. The `find` command is awkward where it is -- that's what prompted the actual test for dir.

Comment: You script works for simple example on my machine. May be you have a typo in the input file (list.txt), leading/trailing spaces, etc. Try running the script with 'bash -x'. Consider sharing list.txt and the file tree, so that SO users can replicate

Comment: So you're looking for just folder/directories and not files? Also I hope that `list.txt` has the entry one per line and not in one line.

Comment: @Jetchisel Yes I'm looking for folders not files.

Comment: @dash-o I tried running the script with bash -x and what I found out is that into fileList variable is stored "Folder_1\r" instead "Folder_1". Do you know what that means?

Comment: @dash-o I forgot to mention that I'm running this script on Ubuntu under Win10. So I tested my script on virtual machine and it works just fine :) But I need it to make it work on Ubuntu running under Win10 :/

Comment: That means you're script has windows line endings, and you should mention that from the start if you're on windows or not...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is an alternative script that might do what you want and it does not use `cat` and a `for loop` but a `while read loop`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

##: Loop through the output of find
while IFS= read -ru 5 -d '' directories; do
  while IFS=$' \r\t\n' read -r list; do  ##: Loop through the output of list.txt
    if [[ $directories = *"$list" ]]; then  ##: If both match
     printf 'Found match directory %s is %s in %s\n' "$directories" "$list" list.xt ##: Print a message that the match
    fi
  done < list.txt
done 5< <(find myFiles/ -type d -print0) ##: -print0 to delimit with null bytes
```

---

EDIT: Change the value of `IFS` for the reading the file to `IFS=$' \r\t\n'` to match the carriage returns from the file.

Assuming `list.txt` has one entry per line and not in one line.

Answer (score 0):

Per input from OP there are windows line endings in the file.
Run dos2unix or  recreate the file on Linux using vi/enacts on Linux should address the problem.